# Java Arraylist Function Program

Tags: java, for-loop

I have this function:

```
public static void display(ArrayList<String> combinations) {
    
    int counter = 1;

    for (char c1 = 'a'; c1 <= 'z'; c1++) {
        for (char c2 = 'a'; c2 <= 'z'; c2++) {
            for (char c3 = 'a'; c3 <= 'z'; c3++) {
                String combo = "" + c1 + c2 + c3;                    
                combinations.add(combo);
                System.out.println("" + counter++ + " " + c1 + c2 + c3);
            }
        } 
    }
```

And this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
List<String> combinations = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println(combinations);
```

I want to use the function I developed and store in array list. Then output the data stored in the arraylist to the user using the function/method.

Comment: just change the return type to `List<String>` instead of `void`, and return your list from the method. in the Main method its just simple assignment `combinations = display()`;

Comment: Thank you Sayan. Would you be able to show me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifiy the `display` method by :

1. Change the method `display` return type from `void` to `List<String>` .
2. return the `combination` list .

```
public static  List<String> display(ArrayList<String> combinations){

//rest of your code

return combinations;
}
```

And now all you have to to is just call the method fromm `main`and assign the returned value into a `List` variable.

```
List<String> combinations = display(new ArrayList<>());
```

You need have a basic idea what is return and how its work. [Refer here](https://www.javatpoint.com/return-statement-in-java#:%7E:text=Returning%20a%20Value%20from%20a,t%20require%20any%20return%20statement.)